# ASP.NET MVC4 "Getting Started" Configuration Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to get started with ASP.NET MVC but everytime I try the following error appears:

https://gist.github.com/Mythli/fd2010373157b819bf23

Is there any easy solution to this error?

Comment: Have you added a reference to `MySQL.Web` assembly?

Comment: No, thank you! Submit this as answer and I accept it.

Comment: Would you please clarify your downvote?

Comment: Although it wasn't me who placed this down vote, I can guess the reason pretty easily. At first, instead of external link well formed answer would contain error text in it, cut down to relevant part. At second, SO language is English, so you cannot expect people to understand error message in German. There is always Google translate of course (that what I used btw), but if you want people to help you - make an effort to clarify your problem for them.

Comment: I can't say what the relevant part is so I thought including the whole error message is most useful. But you are right. I forgot to translate the error message- sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you did not referenced `MySql.Web` assembly. Add this reference and the error will go away.